# Polynomial ring $S[X]$ over domain $S$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be a local integral domain and $S[X]$ be a polynomial ring.

Choose $f, g$ from $S[X]$ as follows:

$f:= X^n + c_{n-1}X^{n-1} + ... + c_1X + c_0$

$g:= a_mX^m + ... + a_0$,

where $a_0, a_1,...,a_m$ all lie in the unique maximal ideal $m_S$ of $S$.

> If $g$ is irreducible, does the ideal $(f,g)$ contain a non-trivial element of $S$ other than zero?

Comment: Why not if, for example $\deg f=0$?

Comment: If $g$ is prime, then the answer is yes. One shows that multiplication by $g$ on $S[X]/(f)$ is injective and thus has a nontrivial determinant. And a matrix times its adjoint  is the determinant times the identity matrix.

Comment: @PierreMATSUMI It's really sad that after more than 3 years you did not accept any answer to your questions.

Answer (score 6):

No. Take for $S$  the ring of real power series in $t$ for which the coefficients 
of $t$ and $t^3$ both vanish. 
Take $f:=X^2-t^6$, $g:=t^5+t^2X$. 
We must check that there is no $h$ so that $gh$ is
a nonzero constant modulo $f$. This is straightforward.

Comment: Because g is irreducible, this means (g) is prime. Then as you say, the answer is Yes, isn't it? What's the relation of your example of real formal power series ring? Pierre

Comment: No, that is false. In my answer $g$ is irreducible, but $(g)$ is not prime. Could you rephrase your question about `the relation' ?

Comment: Dear Wilberd van der Kallen, thanks a lot. Pierre Matsumi

Comment: @Pierre MATSUMI.This is not the way it is done. If you agree, you should accept the answer.